# how to display selected items in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

what I want to achieve is to display the list of all selected items and data binding between them. For saying this is the list

List:

[.] A

```
B 

C
```

[.] D

```
F
```

Display Selected list:

```
 [-]   A (1)  [+]

 [-]   D (1)  [+]
```

I'm wondering where to start this and here List and Display Selected list should be in synch. whenever we increment or decrement items it should reflect the same in both lists.

**Note: how can we achieve this without checkboxes ?**

Comment: here B & C are the items in A and F is Array D ?

Comment: @SatishPai here A and D are selected item similar to check box